# Ho do you call Vuex module Action from Vue component action?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Let's say i have Vuex store module `storeModuleName`, and i want to invoke its action from some component.

Component:

```js
export default {
  actions: {
   close() {
     dispatch('storeModuleName/storeModuleAction');
   },
  }
...
```

Error:

```
dispatch is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `mapActions`, mapActions let you connect with actions inside modules

```
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      storeModuleActionName: "storeModuleName/storeModuleAction"
    })
  },
  mounted(){
    this.storeModuleActionName();
  }
}
```

And then you can use `storeModuleActionName` as a normal method, [Check the link about mapActions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions-in-components)